# Как расположить текстовый блок в отчете FastReport между двумя таблицами?

Tags: fastreport

В отчете должны быть 2 таблицы и текст из нескольких строк, расположенный между этими двумя таблицами. Текст никак не связан с данными в этих таблицах.
Таблицы строятся с помощью бэндов Header и MasterData. Если добавить текст в бэнд Footer к первой таблице, то это приводит к тому, что если Footer переносится на следующую страницу, то перед ним повторяется заголовок таблицы. Расположить просто текст между бэндами редактор отчетов не дает.

**UPD:** Скриншоты

[image: Вариант с двумя таблицами]
[image: Вариант с двумя таблицами]

Comment: Можете приложить к вопросу скрины из дизайнера, как было, и как с сабрепортами сейчас?

Comment: Добавил скриншоты

Comment: Игнорируйте мои комментарии, я думал что таблицы и текст вы хотите расположить по горизонтали )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете расположить текст между бэндами, добавив его в отдельный МастерДата. У этого МастерДата укажите (двойной клик на МастерДата) источник данных >пусто< и количество раз вывода = 1.